# How do I compose HOCs without getting a type-error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

In our application we use [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) (exposing the HOC `withNamespaces`) and [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) (exposing the HOC `withStyles`) and we have to use typescript. Some components need both translations and styling, so they have props like

```
interface MyCompProps extends WithStyles, WithNamespaces {
    // actually relavent props here
}
```

and are exported with both HOCs

```
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(withNamespaces()(MyComp as any)) as typeof MyComp;
```

This has some problems, for example:

1. Nesting the function calls like that is unreadable
2. We need two casts (`as any`, `as typeof MyComp`) for this to work, otherwise we get type-errors. Sometimes we still get type-errors after casting.

If we had plain JS I'd write

```
export default compose(
    withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true }),
    withNamespaces()
)(MyComp)
```

But in TS this function returns a `{}` instead of a `typeof MyComp` (without WithStyles and WithNamespaces) as I'd expect.
I can force it to be a `typeof MyComp`, but then the usage of this component complains that I don't set the fields for `WithStyles` and `WithNamespaces`.

How do I compose these HOCs so that the resulting type is correct? 
As far as I understand the resulting type should be `ComponentClass<MyCompProps>` without the fields of `WithStyles` and `WithNamespaces`.